# How to change straight quotes to curly quotes in CK editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

How to change straight quotes to curly quotes in ckeditor like MSword quotes. How can i do that please give me solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in CKeditor website. It has a plugin called ("Autocorrect") solved my problem. If anyone having this problem install this plugin into CK editor plugins folder.
https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/autocorrect